# What is the proper way to archive a Thunderbird mailbox

Tags: email, thunderbird

The credentials of my former job have become invalid but I'd like to keep the mailbox content among my other functional e-mail accounts.

I've disabled synchronization for this account. However Thunderbird keeps retrieving mailboxes from time to time, e.g. at startup, or when the mailbox folder is clicked.

How do we properly tell Thunderbird not to synchronize anything with an account?

Answer (score 3):

All **local** mail is in your profile in one or both of the folders *Mail* and *ImapMail*. For example, in Windows, those folders are in C:\Users\{user-name}\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\{profile-name} .

To keep all messages in an account without receiving more:

- In Thunderbird, create in *Local Folders* new folders with the *name of each account*.
- Copy all messages in the online account to the appropriate local folder, e.g. by dragging and dropping each account's *Inbox*, *Sent*, *Archive*, etc. into the folder.
- Delete the account; your saved messages are all on your machine, now, in folders *Mail* and *ImapMail*.

Comment: That's not very satisfying, since it will break the `Unified Folder` view with all outboxes and inboxes at the same location. Isn't it possible to switch from `imap://` to local `mailbox://` directly in the config editor?

Comment: However, it's the most reliable. Until a message is read, and any data (e.g. images or attachments) downloaded, the body of the message may be on the IMAP server, and only the header is in your Inbox.

Comment: the path on mac should be: `/Users/<user-name>/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/`